# How to do 3D sides-of-cube transition between view controllers in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

[**SPUN**](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/spun-city-news-magazine/id575348873?mt=8) app for

iPhone has a great vertical 3D transition between view controllers. What are some open source

libraries designed for this purpose or similar cool transition effects?

[image: Spun app]

Comment: I haven't used that specific app, but the easiest way to tackle this would be dive straight into segues: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

There are some open source ones here: http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/01/15/custom-view-controller-transitions-using-uistoryboardsegues/